# Giant spacing between stackView, imageView and title in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistackview, spacing

I'm studying Swift and building my UI in Xcode and it seems ok in storyboard.

[outline and canvas in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2VvA.jpg)

But when I run simulator, there's a giant spacing between Top Navigation Stack View, Detailed Image View and Title Label.

[giant spacing 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqgwD.jpg)

[giant spacing 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CVBB.jpg)

I've tried to post as much info about each stackView their attribute inspectors.

[Main Stack View Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJwcE.jpg)

[Top Navigation Stack View Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygHcL.jpg)

[Content Stack View Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb4gA.jpg)

What am I doing wrong? How can I get just usual 20-30 spacing between all of my content?

Uptade: i've found a solution. I've just set height constraint of Detailed Image View explicitly to 520. Not the best one, but at least it works on all iPhone screen sizes.

Comment: Is the warning related to any missing constraint ?

Comment: @PtitXav no, it's just tells about empty unreachable collectionVC on the left

Comment: @ekstrak - give your views (labels, the "name" view, the image view, etc) different background colors. That will make it much easier to see what's happening with the frames and spacing.

Comment: @DonMag totally forgot about that, thanks. I just realized that I don't know what these intervals are between.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -2):

check the align, spacing and distribution values, the size of your views inside of the stack maybe set in all the view, and I see a scrollview... maybe you set the stack constraints in the scrollview top, bottom, leading, trailing for the stack.... if you set value stack for distribution, fillProportionally, and set a constraint bottom with lessThanOrEqualTo... try with that.. maybe help.